# how to make href from Ext.form.Label?

Tags: extjs

I have a label:

```
url= new Ext.form.Label()
url.setText("test");
```

but url is escaped.

Comment: What do you mean with escaped?

Comment: I don't understand.. you want to make an anchor tag.. can you put your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an URL from the text of the label :

```
{
   xtype:'label',
   text:'<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>'
}
```

This kind of code won't generate a hyperlink. Instead use a displayfield:

```
{
   xtype:'displayfield',
   value:'<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>'
}
```